# How to select a song from the search result in youtube?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click a song out of a list on `Youtube`. 
I'll try make things easy without sharing all my classes, but still show you the elements I'm using.

```
IwebDriver  _webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
_webdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
var element = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("search")));
element.SendKeys("Perfect");
var element = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#search-icon-legacy>yt-icon")));
element.Click();
var content = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("contents")));
var songHREF = content.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#video-title"));
songHREF[2].Click();
```

So, main thing that happens is that 90% of the runs, the `songHREF` will click on an object(song's link) that actually located on the main page and not the "results" page.
The other 10% it just fails. It doesn't find the `songHREF` element(element not visible).

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait until element will be clickable:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(songHREF[2]));
songHREF[2].Click()
```

This will wait a least 1 minute until element will be clickable and only then clicks on it.

Full code would be like this:

```
IwebDriver  _webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
_webdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
var element = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("search")));
element.SendKeys("Perfect");
var element = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#search-icon- 
legacy>yt-icon")));
element.Click();
// refresh the page
Driver.Instance.Navigate().Refresh();
var content = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("contents")));
var songHREF = content.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#video-title"));
var wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
wait2.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(songHREF[2]));
songHREF[2].Click();
```

I have catched the issue. Sometimes the locators are working wrong locating invisible elements, but simply refresh the page will help to fix it. Note: refresh the page before you are locating elements like in the code snippet above.

Normal result when search the elements:

[image: img]

Sometimes comes this result with the same locator:

[image: img2]

And the first 25 elements in this case are invisible. But after refreshing the page the result is like in the first case(as expected).

Comment: 10x, but that's might be the fix for 10%. The `click` will eventaully will be executed , but the wrong element will be clicked, since for some reason , it clicks the first page's songs and not the results page's songs.

Comment: Then you have to improve your locator, probably in 10% `songHREF[2]` is not the element you are expecting.

Comment: I have catched the issue. Sometimes the locators are working wrong locating invisible elements, but simply refresh the page will help to fix it. Note refresh the page before you are locating elements. i have added the example in the code

Answer (score 0):

As per your question once you send a character sequence e.g. **Perfect** to the *search* field and initiate search, you can create a *List* of all the songs and then according to your choice e.g. *Song which contains the text **Lyrics** in the heading* you can invoke `Click()` on it and you can use the following solution:

```
IwebDriver  _webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
_webdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
new WebDriverWait(_webdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input#search"))).SendKeys("Perfect");
_webdriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button.style-scope.ytd-searchbox>yt-icon")).Click();
IList<IWebElement> contents = new WebDriverWait(_webdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.CssSelector("h3.title-and-badge.style-scope.ytd-video-renderer a")));
foreach (IWebElement content in contents)
    if(content.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Contains("Lyrics"))
    {
        content.Click();
        break; 
    }
```